# Using Reflection to call a method on a field

Tags: java, reflection, queue

Okay been working on this too long and can't get it to work.  I have a list of Thread types that can be different classes i.e. WriteFileData(extends Thread).  I want to for loop through that list and do a call to add to queue a byte array.  I currently have this in a Broker class

```
// consumers is filled with different Thread types all having a queue
// variable of type LinkedBlockingQueue
ArrayList<Thread> consumers = new ArrayList<Thread>();

synchronized void insert(final byte[] send) throws InterruptedException {
    for (final Thread c : consumers) {
        if (c instanceof WriteFileData) {
            ((WriteFileData)c).queue.add(send);
        } 
        ...other class threads...
}
```

but what I want to do is something more along the lines of

```
synchronized void insert(final byte[] send) throws InterruptedException {
    for (final Thread c : consumers) {
       Class<?> cls = Class.forName(c.getClass().getName());
       Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("queue");
       Class<?> cf = Class.forName(field.getType().getName());
       Class[] params = new Class[]{Object.class};

       Method meth = cf.getMethod("offer", params);

       meth.invoke(cf, send);  // errors at this line....
```

**EDIT:  Fixed "method not found error" but now can't seem to invoke method due to I'm sending it an Array and its method wants just an Object.**

.... alas it errors out at meth.invoke.  Not sure how to do this as this is many levels deep, I wanted to use the add method on queue but that is one more layer of class abstraction.

Here is what WriteFileData has...

```
public class WriteFileData extends Thread {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();

...
}
```

Comment: what is the declaration for `offer` method?

Comment: Sorry to answer a question with a question. But why reflection?  If there is an alternative to using reflection you should use it.  Reflection is capable of REALLY breaking some stuff in ways you don't expect.

Could you include the exception and error message.  I you want us to debug this we need to know whats wrong.

Comment: JPM, please say what your error from getDeclaredMethod() is.  It sounds like you want to have your Thread classes implement a Java interface so you can call a common method.  Do you have control of the classes that are  your threads?

Comment: error is method not found... Reason why I want to do this is so that the Broker class doesn't need to know the or import the classes for the thread types.  I can call them generically and add the queue data to them.  So that inthe future I can abstract this layer and not care what Thread class it calls it will just know it by what's in the list.

Comment: In my world the obvious thing would be to create an interface with an  offer() method, having all the threads implement that interface and iterate over that instead.I don't understand what you need reflection for and besides it's a big no-no in calling a field directly. If I were to do code review on this you'd get an instant fail.

Comment: Because I can't go back and change the other Thread classes I can only use what I got, so there must be a way to invoke a method on a field Class(LinkedBlockingQueue) passing it a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did with some advice from @Erik.

Here is WriteFileData with added method add(byte[] send) ...

```
public class WriteFileData extends Thread {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();

    public void add(byte[] send) {
        queue.add(send);
    }

...
}
```

And now my Broker class method looks like this:

```
public synchronized void insert(final byte[] send) {
    for (final Thread c : consumers) {
    try {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(c.getClass().getName());
        Method meth = cls.getMethod("add", new Class[]{byte[].class});
        meth.invoke(c, send);
```