# How to invoke a method of a field member of a class through reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

The approach below gives me a **NoSuchMethodException**

```
package a.b.c;
class A{
    B b;
}


package x.y.z;

class Main{

    private void doSomething(){
        try{
            Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("a.b.c.A");
            Field bField = aClass.getDeclaredField("b");
            bField.setAccessible(true);

            //This didn't work as it gives me a NoSuchMethodException
            Class<?> bObj = bField.getType();
            Method cFilterMethod = bObj.getMethod("setColorFilter", new Class[]{Integer.class, PorterDuff.Mode.class});
            cFilterMethod.invoke(bObj, new PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffff00,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));   

            // So I tried looking for all the methods inside bObj
            // This prints all the methods of the java.lang.Class instead of class B
              Method[] methods = bObj.getMethods();
              for(Method method : methods){
                    Log.d("TAG", ""+ method.getName());
              }

        }// Exception Handling Code
    }
}
```

So, the basic question is,

> How to invoke a method of a field member of a class ?

I have to invoke the **setColorFilter** method of field **b** which is a default member of class **A**.

The reason why I am using reflection is that the **package a.b.c** above is closed source.

**PS:** I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453324/using-reflection-to-call-a-method-on-a-field) and I am not able to find the solution for my problem there ?

Comment: What is signature of setColorFilter??

Comment: public void setColorFilter (int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)
  [Reference](http://ow.ly/vFBK7)

Comment: use int.class. Like `new Class[]{int.class, PorterDuff.Mode.class}` into getMethod(). This will do your task.